# Navigation on OctoberCMS with Static Pages plugin

Tags: php, html, laravel, navigation, octobercms

I'm developing landing page with October CMS and using Static Pages plugin.
Here is my header.htm file with navigation:

```
<div class="header" id="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header__inner">
            <div class="header__logo">
                <img src="{{ 'assets/img/logo.svg'|theme }}" alt="logo" class="logo">
            </div>
            <nav class="nav" id="nav">
                {% partial 'menu-items' items=staticMenu.menuItems class='nav__list' %}
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Question is how to modify basic menu-items.htm partial if I'am using one page layout and I want exact section be active on menu item click (not separate page as it is now).

At the moment I have menu with such items and want one of these section be active on click:

```
/, 
/#about, 
/#projects, 
/#contacts.
```

My menu-items.htm partial is below:

```
<ul class="{{ class }}">
    {% for item in items %}
        <li 
            class="nav__item {{ item.isActive or item.isChildActive ? 'active' : '' }} 
            {{ item.items ? 'dropdown' : '' }}"
        >
            <a class="nav__link"
                {% if item.items %}class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"{% endif %} 
                href="{{ item.url }}"
            >
                {{ item.title }}

                {% if item.items %}<span class="caret"></span>{% endif %}
            </a>

            {% if item.items %}
                {% partial 'menu-items' items=item.items class='dropdown-menu' %}
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

At the moment code in menu-items.htm partial if statement add "active" class on click because of this line:

```
<li class="nav__item {{ item.isActive or item.isChildActive ? 'active' : '' }} {{ item.items ? 'dropdown' : '' }}"
```

...it is because item "isActive" property is "true" when exact menu item is clicked. But my question is, how to do the same (add "active" class) with section link in meniu navigation, because my project have only one page "home" and several sections in it. so I want menu navigation link be active on fixed navigation when someone click for eaxmple "About" link and scroll to /#about section.

Comment: Not understanding your question could you post maybe some images to show what you are specifically trying to do.

Comment: @Pettis code in menu-items.htm partial if statement add "active" class on click because of this line:
<li class="nav__item {{ item.isActive or item.isChildActive ? 'active' : '' }} {{ item.items ? 'dropdown' : '' }}"
...it is because item "isActive" property is "true" when exact menu item is clicked. But my question is, how to do the same (add "active" class) with section link in menu navigation, because my project have only one page "home" and several sections in it. I want menu navigation link be active on navigation when someone click for exmple "About" link and scroll to /#about section.

Comment: Well there are numerous ways to do what you want. You can just use JavaScript / Jquery or you can push data into the session and update the menu partial. There might be a way to do it with CSS. Jquery would probably be the easiest. IE: `$('#about').click(function(){$(this).addClass('.active');});` Try something and if you get stuck then come back with a more specific question.

Comment: @Pettis many thanks for your advise, please see my solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/64151201/7895443 Just maybe it is more correct way (based on good practices). I mean AJAX and etc?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote just several lines of Jquery (thanks to Pettis Brandon advise).

```
$('.nav__item').click(function(){
  $('.nav__item').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active')
});
```

It removes 'active' class from '.nav__item' class and after that add it again on corresponding link, based on {{ item.url }}. Hope it helps for the other as well (who is using Static Pages plugin).